# Type error in command pattern

Tags: c#, command-pattern

I am trying to implement a command pattern with strongly typed input and output parameters for the command itself.

First of all I have created two interfaces that marks the input and the output for the command:

```
interface IRequest { }
interface IResponse { }
```

Then I have created the base classes and interfaces. This is the abstract receiver

```
interface IReceiver<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest
    where TResponse : IResponse
{
    TResponse Action( TRequest request );
}
```

and this the abstract command

```
abstract class AbstractCommand<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest
    where TResponse : IResponse
{
    protected IReceiver<TRequest, TResponse> _receiver;

    public AbstractCommand( IReceiver<TRequest, TResponse> receiver ) {
        _receiver = receiver;
    }

    public abstract TResponse Execute( TRequest request );
}
```

Now I am trying to use these objects and so I have created the needed concrete classes

```
class TypeARequest : IRequest
{
    public TypeARequest() {
    }

    public int NumericValueA { get; set; }
    public int NumericValueB { get; set; }
}

class TypeAResponse : IResponse
{
    public TypeAResponse() {
    }

    public int Result { get; set; }
}

class SumCommand : AbstractCommand<TypeARequest, TypeAResponse>
{
    public SumCommand( IReceiver<TypeARequest, TypeAResponse> receiver ) : base( receiver ) {
    }

    public override TypeAResponse Execute( TypeARequest request ) {
        return _receiver.Action( request );
    }
}

class SumReceiver : IReceiver<TypeARequest, TypeAResponse>
{
    public TypeAResponse Action( TypeARequest request ) {
        return new TypeAResponse() { Result = request.NumericValueA + request.NumericValueB };
    }

}
```

Finally I have created a CommandProcessor class which should be able to process multiple commands altogether

```
class CommandProcessor
{
    IList<AbstractCommand<IRequest, IResponse>> _supportedCommands = new List<AbstractCommand<IRequest, IResponse>>();

    public CommandProcessor() {
    }

    void AddSupportedCommand( AbstractCommand<IRequest, IResponse> item ) {
        _supportedCommands.Add( item );
    }

    void SetupSupportedCommands() {
        // ERROR HERE 
        AddSupportedCommand( new SumCommand( new SumReceiver() ) );
    }

}
```

However I am getting a compile time error saying:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'SumCommand' to
>   'AbstractCommand'

Any help or suggestion?

Comment: I guess this is your catch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/index and this also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an interface and mark your generic parameter as covariance example:

```
interface IRequest { }
interface IResponse { }
interface IReceiver<in TRequest, out TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest
    where TResponse : IResponse
{
    TResponse Action(TRequest request);
}

interface ICommand<out TRequest, out TResponse>
{

}

abstract class AbstractCommand<TRequest, TResponse> : ICommand<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest   
    where TResponse : IResponse
{
    protected IReceiver<TRequest, TResponse> _receiver;

    public AbstractCommand(IReceiver<TRequest, TResponse> receiver)
    {
        _receiver = receiver;
    }

    public abstract TResponse Execute(TRequest request);
}

class CommandProcessor
{
    IList<ICommand<IRequest, IResponse>> _supportedCommands = new List<ICommand<IRequest, IResponse>>();

    public CommandProcessor()
    {
    }

    void AddSupportedCommand(ICommand<IRequest, IResponse> item)
    {
        _supportedCommands.Add(item);
    }

    void SetupSupportedCommands()
    {
        AddSupportedCommand(new SumCommand(new SumReceiver()));
    }

}
```

More information here [out modifier msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier)

Comment: Thanks. Actually your solution ends up with an error saying `Invalid variance modifier. Only interface and delegate type parameters can be specified as variant. ` However it seems that can be solved by creating an `ICommand` interface...

Comment: Yes, I was running to that error, I fixing it and updating my solution. sorry wasn't my intention

Comment: No worries I understand. However after following your edit, I am still getting errors: first I can not add "out" to IRequest, then I also get the same error as before. If you put my code in a console program you should get the same error

Comment: In IReciever you cannot add TRequest as covariance you are passing in the constructor you can leave it without "out"

Comment: would like to upvote more than once. I guess I need to learn more about covariance and contravariance :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @Lorenzo, It's a bit difficult to understand at first. I step once at it and caught my attention. good luck

Comment: The problem is now that we have removed the execute method from the ICommand interface. So if I wanted to make a loop on the list of ICommand instances and run the execute I can't do it without downcasting the interface.